# Кастомизация связи "многие ко многим"

Tags: python, orm, django

Есть 2 модели. Одна модель описывает товар, другая описывает опции. Любая из моделей может иметь любые из опций. Следовательно это поле Многие-ко-Многим. Но есть одна проблема. Для товаров это опция обязатеная, а для други - нет. Какбы это организовать в контексте Django ORM?

Answer (score 4):

Возможно вам поможет заведение промежуточной модели, в ней можно хранить флаг обязательности. [Документация](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships).

Comment: Хорошее решение, спасибо за пример. Если ничего с меньшим числом сущностей не придумаю, воспользуюсь именно этим.